# Query a taxonomy or two select lists in Wordpress using ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How I can recode this $args for a query so that either one of the filter conditions when triggered will work? Here's my code. Individually I've tested all the filters and are working fine... but combining it together, i'm stuck. One filter is a taxonomy the other two are select lists. I'm using ACF.

```
$args = array(

            'post_type' => 'pathway',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',

            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'uni_tax',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $the_university_filter,
                ),
            ),

            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'meta_key' => 'entry_level',
                    'meta_value' => $the_entrylevel_filter,

                )
            )

            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'meta_key' => 'state',
                    'meta_value' => $the_state_filter,

                )
            )

       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'pathway',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'uni_tax',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $the_university_filter,
        ),
    ),

);

if ( isset($_POST['entry_level_filter'] ) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'entrylevel',
        'value' => $the_entrylevel_filter,
    );
}

if ( isset($_POST['state_filter'] ) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'state',
        'value' => $the_state_filter,
    );
}
```

Please modify the query args as you see fit. If you have any issue related to the `meta_query` combination, let us know.

`$_POST['entry_level_filter']` is just a supposition that this variable will be used to send data in. Handle the decision making variable as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out, but that didn;t work... I did make some progress though...

Comment: If you need further help, add your progress to the question and include your further questions. Id you have got it then post yhesolution and mark it the answer so other may find it useful.